# Why is the macro %VS160COMNTOOLS% available in Developer Command Prompt But Not In Visual Studio 2019 Itself?

Tags: visual-studio, environment-variables, visual-studio-2019

This is somewhat similar to the question asked here.

[Issue in VS 2019 build with editbin.exe location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68185040/issue-in-vs-2019-build-with-editbin-exe-location)

I have a post build task in my project like this:

```
call "%VS160COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
gacutil.exe /f /silent /i "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)
```

Visual Studio upon building, is unable to resolve the macro, %VS160COMNTOOLS% - it resolves to an empty string with the following output:

***'"VsDevCmd.bat"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.***

***'gacutil.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.***

Why is this and how do we make Visual Studio recognize the macro? The same macro resolves correctly in VS2019 command prompt. Why is this?

[image: Output from command prompt]

Comment: It is not a macro, it is an environment variable.  Set by vsdevcmd.bat, so basic chicken-and-egg.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42809603/17034).